# jQuery remove: $("...").remove() vs .remove("...")

Tags: jquery

Reading the docs, I'd expect `$("#wrap2").remove(".error")` to remove all `.error` elements from `#wrap2`. However looking at this JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/hCGUS/** it doesn't appear to be the case?

```
$(function() {
    $("#wrap1 .error").remove(); // works 
    $("#wrap2").remove(".error"); // fails ...
})​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the jQuery document. I think

```
$("#wrap2").remove(".error");
```

equals to:

```
$("#wrap2.error").remove();
```

Means that an element has id `wrap2` and class `error`

Answer (score 8):

As the docs state, the selector parameter to remove is

> A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be
>   removed.

The first example is what you should use to remove elements with class `error` contained in an element with id `wrap1`.

The second example will find the element with id `wrap2` and then filter that set for elements with class `error`, and remove those elements. That is, it will only remove elements which match `#wrap2.error`.

Answer (score 3):

[The docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) say that when passing an argument, it acts as a filter on the wrapped set it's being called on, so if you have a jQuery set, but only want to remove some of the elements in the set, you can pass a selector to remove just those.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of x1a4's answer, `$("wrap2")` only contains one element, not any of its children. If you did:

```
$("wrap2 *").remove(".error")
```

it would perform identically to your working version.

Answer (score -3):

**Please use removeClass instead of remove**

$("#wrap2").removeClass("error");